# Pass local variables in a vimscript function to python

Tags: vimscript, functions, vimscript-python

For example, I want to use default arguments:

```
function! MakeOrgTable(...)
let l:num_col = a:0 > 0? (a:0) :  0;
python << EOF
import vim
vim.current.buffer[:]=make_table(vim.current.buffer, vim.eval("l:num_col"))
EOF
endfunction
```

But it doesn't work, Vim cannot find `l:num_col`. But I do not want define a global variable like `g:num_col`.

So is there a way to pass local variables in a vimscript function to Python?

I use neovim 0.8.0.

Comment: Is the solution proposed addressing your problem? How can we help you more?

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt Thank you! Your answer is the solution. I'm sorry that I procrastinated.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-) No worries I was just verifying that your need were understood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is related to trailing `;` in the definition of `l:num_col`

I would do:

```
function! MakeOrgTable(...)
let l:num_col = a:0 > 0 ? (a:0) : 0
python << EOF
import vim
vim.current.buffer[:]=make_table(vim.current.buffer, vim.eval("l:num_col"))
EOF
endfunction
```

Another problem is that the method `make_table` is not defined.